# Makefile syntax error in windows: unexpected end of file

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw

I want to use MinGW to compile C++ codes in **win10** using the Makefile below:

```
# Include platform dependent makefiles
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
include Makefile.nt
else
include Makefile.unix
endif

PREFIX:=bin/

#############################################################################
# Default target
all: $(PREFIX)rdf3xdump$(EXEEXT) $(PREFIX)rdf3xload$(EXEEXT) $(PREFIX)rdf3xquery$(EXEEXT) $(PREFIX)rdf3xupdate$(EXEEXT) $(PREFIX)rdf3xembedded$(EXEEXT) $(PREFIX)rdf3xreorg$(EXEEXT) $(PREFIX)translatesparql$(EXEEXT) $(PREFIX)buildmonetdb$(EXEEXT) $(PREFIX)buildpostgresql$(EXEEXT)

#############################################################################
# Collect all sources

include cts/LocalMakefile
include infra/LocalMakefile
include makeutil/LocalMakefile
include rts/LocalMakefile
include gtest/LocalMakefile
include test/LocalMakefile
include api/LocalMakefile

ifeq ($(LINEEDITOR),1)
src_lineeditor:=lineeditor/LineInput.cpp lineeditor/LineEditor.cpp lineeditor/Terminal.cpp lineeditor/Display.cpp lineeditor/Buffer.cpp
endif

include tools/LocalMakefile


source:=$(src_cts) $(src_infra) $(src_rts) $(src_tools) $(src_lineeditor)

#############################################################################
# Dependencies

generatedependencies=$(call nativefile,$(PREFIX)makeutil/getdep) -o$(basename $@).d $(IFLAGS) $< $(basename $@)$(OBJEXT) $(genheaders) $(GENERATED-$<)

ifneq ($(IGNORE_DEPENDENCIES),1)
-include $(addprefix $(PREFIX),$(source:.cpp=.d)) $(addsuffix .d,$(basename $(wildcard $(generatedsource))))
endif

#############################################################################
# Compiling

compile=$(CXX) -c  $(TARGET)$(call nativefile,$@) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS-$(firstword $(subst /, ,$<))) $(IFLAGS) $(IFLAGS-$(firstword $(subst /, ,$<))) $(call nativefile,$<)

$(PREFIX)%$(OBJEXT): %.cpp $(PREFIX)makeutil/getdep$(EXEEXT)
    $(checkdir)
    $(generatedependencies)
    $(compile)

#############################################################################
# Cleanup

clean:
    find bin -name '*.d' -delete -o -name '*.o' -delete -o '(' -perm -u=x '!' -type d ')' -delete

#############################################################################
# Executable

$(PREFIX)query: $(addprefix $(PREFIX),$(source:.cpp=$(OBJEXT)))
```

After I type mingw32-make, some error seems to occur:

```
D:\rdf3x>mingw32-make
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
makeutil/LocalMakefile:3: recipe for target 'bin/makeutil/getdep.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [bin/makeutil/getdep.o] Error 1
```

I also have ever transferred the Makefile to unix-style by dos2unix.
All the makefile and codes are cloned from github: https://github.com/gh-rdf3x/gh-rdf3x. And many other people finished compiling the codes.

How can I fix this problem? My OS is windows10 64bit version, and compiler tool is MinGW

-------------update--------------

Thanks for @MadScientist's remind, file `makeutil/LocalMakefile` is attached below:

```
# Separate build rules to avoid cyclic dependencies
$(PREFIX)makeutil/getdep$(OBJEXT): makeutil/getdep.cpp
    $(checkdir)
    $(compile)

$(PREFIX)makeutil/getdep$(EXEEXT): $(PREFIX)makeutil/getdep$(OBJEXT)
    $(buildexe)
```

Comment: Well, the error message clearly says the problem is in the file `makeutil/LocalMakefile` at line 3.  You haven't shown us any of that file, so there's no way we can guess what the problem might be.  However, it's not a dos2unix thing (I wouldn't expect) because GNU make can use Windows CRLF linefeeds without transformation (also if it were that you'd get an error much earlier in the parsing).

Comment: Thanks for your remind, I have republished the file 'LocalMakefile' in the description of this issue, is there any problem?@MadScientist

Comment: It looks like your makefiles file afoul of the common problem of "@-everywhere", where people prefix all their commands with @ so no one can see what the command is.  I expect that `checkdir` expands to some shell command which is illegal but starts with @ so make won't print it out and you can't see it.  You should remove all or most of the @ signs in your makefiles and use `.SILENT` instead: see http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/ for some tips.  Anyway, until we see what `$(checkdir)` expands to we can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

`$(checkdir)` expands to something (you're not showing us what) that isn't a complete shell command.